# Mongoose reading new Decimal128('1.2') from MongoDB that has 1.2

Tags: json, mongodb, flutter, mongoose

I've been having trouble with mongoose saving Number as an integer (when it should be a float/double) in our MongoDB database so we switched to using 128 decimal and now it writes fine but when I try to read it back the response comes back as "new Decimal128("1.2") instead of just 1.3.

Rev is the number that I'm trying to save to the db from Flutter and read back in.

Mongo DB results has:

```
rev 1.3
starRating 3
dateCreated 1708412344794
```

Schema:

```
const { Types, model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

const InfoSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    rev: {
    
        type: Types.Decimal128
    },
    starRating: {
        type: Types.Decimal128
    },
```

Console.log:

```
description: 'test',
rev: new Decimal128("1.3"),
starRating: new Decimal128("3"),
dateCreated: 1708412344794,
```

I either need to find a way to safely write and read floating/double data types or figure out why and how the new Decimal128() is getting tacked on and where/how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in a mismatch in the datatypes between BSON and javascript.

In javascript, all numbers are stored as 64-bit floating point.  Upon display javascript automatically trims the decimal point and trailing zeros, if possible.

BSON (https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) has int32, uint64, int64, double, and decimal128.

When store documents containing numbers, mongoose and/or the driver must make a guess whether or not you meant to use one of the 'int' types.  When reading the documents, those must be converted to javascript Number type.

When reading from the database using mongoose both int and float are converted to Number, so there is no difference between float and int on the client side.

Since decimal128 uses 128 bits, there is no automatic process that will truncate that to 64 bits to fit in a Number.

You might consider using a mongoose plugin such as double https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mongoosejs/double.